# Error in proof that regular spaces are normal

Tags: general-topology

I was trying to prove that all ordered topologies are normal, but I have convinced myself that every regular space is normal, since I didn't use the order topology at all. This is clearly not true, so I was wondering where I'm making a mistake.

Let $X$ be a regular space, and let $A,B\subset X$ be disjoint closed sets. For each $a\in A$ we can take disjoint opens $U_a, V_a$ around $a$ and $B$ respectively by regularity. Since $B\cap U_a=\varnothing$ for all $a$, we see that $U=\bigcup U_a$ is disjoint from $B$. I claim that $\bar U$ is disjoint from $B$: let $b\in B$ be a limit point of $U$, then for any neighbourhood $V$ of $b$ there is some $x\in V\cap U$. It follows that $x\in U_a$ for some $a\in A$, and therefore $U_a$ couldn't have been separated from $B$, contrary to the assumption that $X$ is regular. By contradiction we see that no limit point of $U$ is part of $B$. So $\bar U$ is disjoint from $B$ and closed. Now we can do the same trick as before to find a open $V$ around $B$, disjoint from $\bar U$. In conclusion $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$, in other words $X$ is normal.

It would be especially helpful if you could provide an example of a non-normal regular space that shows why it shouldn't work.

My second question would be how I can fit in the order topology to make the proof work, or if I should approach this in an entirely different fashion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane the Moore plane is a good example of space that is regular but is not normal.

Comment: I dispute therefore U_a couldn't have been separated from B.   The proof which I have that proves an order topology is monotonically normal, a stronger version of normal, is an intricate yet simpler proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the sentence "it follows that $x\in U_a$ for some $a\in A$." Notice that this $a$ can depend on $V$.  To infer "$U_a$ couldn't have been separated from $B$," you'd need a single $a$ that works for all $V$ simultaneously.